# Is there a naming convention for the package alias in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, naming-conventions, libraries

How to find the naming convention for the package alias ? e.g.

`import pandas as pd`

pd is the alias of pandas. For the less common packages, is there an alias naming convention ?

Comment: np is for numpy which is a pretty common on especially with pandas

Answer (score 3):

- Avoid a package alias unless the name of the package is very frequently used throughout your code.
- Don't use an alias unless you've seen a lot of other people using the same one (this one is courtesy of *Mark Ransom*).
- Use a 2-letter alias (1-letter and 3-letter aliases are also sometimes used), for example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import datetime as dt
import sqlalchemy as sa
import math as m
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

Comment: Another thing I'd add, don't use an alias unless you've seen a lot of other people using the same one.

Comment: And thanks for the credit, it wasn't necessary.